# Как изменить шрифт во всем приложении?

Tags: android, android-studio, шрифты, textview

Долго искал код для того чтобы сделать кастомный шрифт на все приложение

и наконец то нашел его! Огромное спасибо Глебу Кравченко!

Ссылка на источник: http://dajver.blogspot.com/2014/10/blog-post.html

Answer (score 5):

Суть в том, что нам необходимо создать класс-утилиту которая будет создавать TypeFace и конвертировать все вьюхи в нужный нам шрифт, вот как он будет выглядеть:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class TypefaceUtil {
    public static void overrideFont(Context context, String defaultFontNameToOverride, String customFontFileNameInAssets) {
        try {
            final Typeface customFontTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), customFontFileNameInAssets);
            final Field defaultFontTypefaceField = Typeface.class.getDeclaredField(defaultFontNameToOverride);
            defaultFontTypefaceField.setAccessible(true);
            defaultFontTypefaceField.set(null, customFontTypeface);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

Затем необходимо создать папку assets и в ней создать папку fonts для наших шрифтов.

Далее нужно добавить эту строку в главное активити, в метод onCreate:

```
TypefaceUtil.overrideFont(getApplicationContext(), "SANS_SERIF", "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
```

Вместо "Roboto-Regular.ttf" вы указываете свой шрифт.

Также можно сделать этот код на какую-нибудь кнопку.

И в заключении добавляете в файл styles.xml эти строки:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Все! Запускаете приложение и наслаждаетесь)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25132568/5490632

overrideFont лучше сделать в Application classe, к примеру будет SplashScreen который может не вызываться иногда.